# Can you input two range values in same variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, range

I had a question can i add two range values in same variable like for example

`A = range(int(input("Enter the range:")))`
Will python allow me to input starting point and ending point of range?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
A = range(int(input("Enter range start : ")), int(input("Enter range end : ")));
```

The range function takes two parameters for start and end. [Range](https://devdocs.io/python~3.7/library/functions#range)
The input function will try to convert all the input in one int.